# Pushed to wrong remote and can't do force push, can't delete branch

Tags: git, github

I searched a lot, but I couldn't find a solution for my specific case. I am doing a series of projects and pushing to my course's remote repository where each project has its own branch (which was already created for me and it is empty at first) so it can be evaluated by the staff.

I finished project 1, but unfortunately I pushed to project 2 branch. As it was empty, it accepted the push:

```
local project 1 repository -> project 2 remote branch
```

After realizing the mistake, I pushed it to the correct remote branch:

```
local project 1 repository -> project 1 remote branch
```

Now I finished project 2 and, as excepted, I couldn't push to project 2's remote:

```
Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
to the same ref.
```

I tried to force push, but the branch is protected and I don't own the repository to temporally allow it:

```
remote: error: Cannot force-push to this protected branch
```

Using git log, it shows both pushes as a single hash:

```
2a0e3dr (HEAD -> master, origin/projects/project1, origin/projects/project2) Finished project
```

I worked alone in those projects and I did only a single push to these remotes. I just want to be able to push my local project 2 to its remote branch and I don't care about its history or deleting everything in project 2's remote branch. Could someone point me to a solution?

Comment: Since you cannot force push to a protected branch, and you probably are not allowed to delete the remote branch, why not just forget about it? Just push to a _different_ branch in the project 2 remote. (Alternatively, you could send an email to whoever has the power here and ask _them_ to delete the incorrectly created branch for you.)

Comment: And while you are at it, have them fix the remote repository. You appear to have either too many or too few permissions in that repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this issue by going to project's 1 local repository and typing:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

This command unstages all files, as if I have deleted them, but it does not modify the actual files in the local repository

If i do `git status` at this point:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    unwanted_file1
    deleted:    unwanted_file2
```

After that, I committed the changes and pushed to project's 2 remote branch:

```
git commit -m "Deleted files pushed by mistake"

git push origin master:project2
```

Now the remote branch does not have any files.

Then I tried to push the correct files from project 2's local repository, but this failed, as the project 2's remote branch and local have different histories. So I just moved the project's 2 files to project 1 local repository, added to staging area, committed the correct files and pushed to project 2's remote:

```
git add correct_file1 correct_file2
git commit -m "Added files from correct project"
git push origin master:project2
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset your commits and stash your changes

`git reset --soft origin/<branch-name> && git stash`

Switch to project 2 branch and see the files

`git checkout project2_branch_name && git pull`

then you can delete all the files in your git repo

`git rm -r *` then commit changes `git commit -m "delete wrong files"`

then push to repo `git push origin project2_branch_name`

you can then get your stashed changes by `git stash pop`

then add push the correct files to repo,

`git add . && git commit -m "your message" && git push project2_branch_name`

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. I understand that git stash stores the uncommitted changes to be applied later by git stash pop, but I think you are assuming that project 1 and 2 are in the same local git repository, when in reality they are in different local repositories, so I would not be able to apply the stashed code to the correct branch. Maybe I could do a git revert to the remote repository from local project 1 repository so the remote branch is empty again and push from project 2 local repository? Do you think it would work?

Comment: Yes. If that's the case, just reset the repo by deleting files in the repo. You will have to remove the files both and commit those changes to remote so that repo is empty. Then just copy the files over. Then commit and push the right files.